# Convert time based on timezone using java.time

Tags: java, time, java-8, java-time

How to change the time based on timezone in **LocalDateTime**, here i have built a date with Time zone as *EST*, now i need to find the *UTC* of the corresponding time. please help me how to solve this

```
String str = "16Jun2015_153556";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMMyyyy_HHmmss");
formatter.withZone(ZoneId.of("EST5EDT"));
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
```

Comment: The expression `formatter.withZone(ZoneId.of("EST5EDT"));` is useless because you don't assign it to any instance of `DateTimeFormatter`. Remember that this class is immutable so all changes can only be achieved by copying, not manipulating the same instance. And setting the timezone this way does not affect parsing to `LocalDateTime` (zone will be ignored).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer might be somehow more structured than the correct answer of Jon Skeet. In my comment above I have also pointed out not to overlook the immutable nature of `DateTimeFormatter` so please always assign the result of any method prefixed by "with...()" to a variable of same type.

```
// parsing your string input
// NO!!! timezone is needed in this step because LocalDateTime is just without timezone
String str = "16Jun2015_153556";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMMuuuu_HHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);

System.out.println(ldt); // your input as java.time-object: 2015-06-16T15:35:56
```

Then you assign your local date-time to the EST-zone. It is safer to use the IANA-notation "America/New_York" than to use the outdated form "EST5EDT" (which is only supporting fixed dst rules without any history of historical raw offsets).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
```

Finally you transform the intermediate global timestamp back to a local date-time at the offset UTC+00 preserving the same physical time:

```
LocalDateTime utc = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
System.out.println(utc); // 2015-06-16T19:35:56
```

Answer (score 12):

You shouldn't think about "changing the time zone" of a `LocalDateTime` - a `LocalDateTime` doesn't *have* a time zone. Instead, you should build a `ZonedDateTime` from a `LocalDateTime` and a time zone (`ZoneId`). First remove the `formatter.withZone` call, then use:

```
ZonedId zone = ZoneId.of("EST5EDT"); // Or preferrably "America/New_York"
ZonedDateTime zoned = ZonedDateTime.of(dateTime, zone);
```

Then you could convert that to an instant, or perhaps use:

```
ZonedDateTime utc = zoned.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

So for example:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "16Jun2015_153556";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMMyyyy_HHmmss");
        ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
        ZonedDateTime zoned = ZonedDateTime.of(dateTime, zone);

        // Both of these print 2015-06-16T19:35:56Z
        System.out.println(zoned.toInstant()); 
        System.out.println(zoned.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    }
}
```